Ubuntu 24.04 Remote Login connects to black screen
I have been wanting to use the built in Remote Login feature that was added to Ubuntu, but after connecting to the server I am left with a black screen. I'm unsure what the cause is as the logs don't seem to point to anything in particular.
Output of journalctl /usr/libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon -f while attempting to connect:
gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1119]: [23:24:42:342] [1119:00009a43] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.tpkt] - [tpkt_ensure_stream_consumed_]: [rdp_read_info_packet] Received invalid TPKT header length 608, 214 bytes too long!
org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.Handover.desktop[39794]: Cannot load libcuda.so.1
org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.Handover.desktop[39794]: Cannot load libnvidia-encode.so.1
gnome-remote-de[39794]: RDP server started
gnome-remote-de[1119]: [RDP] Sending server redirection
gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1119]: [23:24:43:191] [1119:00009a43] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [rdp_set_error_info]: ERRINFO_LOGOFF_BY_USER [0x0001000C]
gnome-remote-de[1119]: [RDP] Network or intentional disconnect, stopping session
gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[1119]: [23:24:43:192] [1119:0000045f] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - [transport_default_write]: BIO_should_retry returned a system error 32: Broken pipe
org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.Handover.desktop[39794]: [23:24:43:240] [39794:00009be7] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.tpkt] - [tpkt_ensure_stream_consumed_]: [rdp_read_info_packet] Received invalid TPKT header length 618, 214 bytes too long!
org.gnome.RemoteDesktop.Handover.desktop[39794]: [23:24:43:369] [39794:00009be7] [WARN][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [peer_unexpected_client_message]: Unexpected client message in state CONNECTION_STATE_FINALIZATION_FONT_LIST, missing flag FINALIZE_CS_FONT_LIST_PDU [0x00000100]
gnome-remote-de[39794]: [RDP.CLIPRDR] Client capabilities: long format names, stream file clip, file clip no file paths, can lock clip data, huge file support
gnome-remote-de[39794]: [RDP.AUDIO_PLAYBACK] Client Formats: [AAC: false, Opus: false, PCM: true]
gnome-remote-de[39794]: [RDP.RDPGFX] CapsAdvertise: Accepting capability set with version RDPGFX_CAPVERSION_106, Client cap flags: H264 (AVC444): true, H264 (AVC420): true

I have a different system also running Ubuntu 24.04 that loads perfectly, and I have compared the logs between the two and I'm not seeing anything that stands out. It looks like everything starts up successfully but I am left with a black screen.
This issue occurs on either desktop sharing or remote login. I tried desktop sharing to make sure that it wasn't some sort of headless issue, so I made sure that it had a monitor attached and was displaying the desktop and attempted to connect and ended with the same black screen. Also, it doesn't seem to be any network connection issue because I can stay connected with a black screen for as long as I want.
Anyone have any ideas?
gnome-remote-desktop v46.3-0

After a pretty extensive amount of debugging, I found that I was having some issue with pipewire and Wayland. I would get the following error when the RDP connection was established:
pipewire remote error: id:0 connection error
I'm not sure what exactly the issue is, but switching to X seems to have fixed the issue. I edited /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommented the line WaylandEnable=false
I am using integrated graphics, which I believe could be related to the issue:
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 03)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    Kernel driver in use: i915

